# Hyper-V on Dell PowerEdge T-105

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, bios, dell-poweredge, amd-v

I am not a hardware expert and am seeking help from them. I bought a Dell PowerEdge T105 server to run a Hyper-V setup for my Dev work. I did not want the OS from them as I already have the OS. So when I configured it on Dell's website I chose it without the OS and when I got it and tried to enable the Hyper-V role on Windows 2008 it gave me an error saying that I have to enable the Virtualization option in the BIOS. To my dismay that option was not there. I called Dell and they said that I would require another processor (AMD Opteron 1214 2.2 GHz Dual Core Processor for Dell PowerEdge T105 Server) instead of what I have. It's going to cost me $289.00 so I checked around locally and the processor was selling for $105, but it came in two options 65W and 103W. I have two questions - which processor should I buy for this? I could not find any information anywhere as to the wattage of the processor and if I put this new processor does the BIOS have to be updated or the Virtualization option would show up in the current BIOS version? I really appreciate any input on this as I sitting with this machine not able to use it for my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 65W version is actually called the 1214HE (high efficiency) and is quite a few months newer than the 103W version - if you want to buy a new processor you should go for the HE version as it'll run cooler, use less power and perhaps last longer if that's of concern.

What I would say though is that if you're prepared to pay $290 just for an old dual-core processor then you should consider spending and extra $80 more, as for that much you can buy a newer FOUR-core T105 ([Clicky](http://configure.euro.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?b=&c=uk&cs=ukbsdt1&kc=N4XM2301&l=en&oc=SV4T105&rbc=SV4T105&s=bsd)) that will be *much* quicker for Hyper-V and you're effectively getting a second PC for $80 - does that make sense?

**EDIT** Sorry, the dell.com site sent me to the dell.co.uk site so the prices and links I provided are invalid sorry. That said the idea still stands, you could consider a new machine for not much more than the price of that old processor, I'll come back with some US-specific pricing when dell let me :)

Edit 2 - [this](http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=bedwlr1&c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&kc=poweredge-t110) T110 machine is a little more than my earlier, wrong, example but is actually a better processor anyway.

Comment: Thanks Chopper3. I am not prepared to pay $290 to Dell, but am going to get from a third party for $120. Since I already have the T105 machine delivered, I cannot exchange it for the T110. All I want to make sure is that if I get the 1214HE, can I use it on the motherboard that has the 1214 currently.

Answer (score 0):

Processor manufacturers are constantly making improvements to processors.

The two you see are the same processor, but the former is much more efficient (consumes almost half the power).

Comment: So is there any incompatibility if I use one or the other with the existing motherboard? I am just worried I don't fry up the machine and lose the processor.

Comment: They are compatible.